# GCP Cloud Memorystore data encryption at rest

Tags: encryption, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

I am unable to find anything that explicitly states that GCP's Memorystore offering (redis) is encrypted at rest.

This document states that "Data at rest is encrypted by default in all Google Cloud Platform products. Read about the granularity of encryption by product.(link)"

https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/

When I click that link and it lists the granularity, however, it lists the specifics for many services, but does not list Memorystore.

https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/default-encryption/#granularity_of_encryption_in_each_google_cloud_platform_product

Is the data in a GCP Memorystore instance encrypted at rest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cloud Memorystore for Redis does not currently support persistence. Therefore there is nothing to encrypt at rest.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I see that there is no persistence. However, data is at temporarily on Google's servers while it is being processed, correct?

Comment: Data is not encrypted in memory by Google Cloud for any service that I am aware of. The only types of services that do are custom developed for special requirements such as for the military, governments or where extreme security is required. Memorystore is not that type of service. Memorystore provides a high-speed Key-Value store.